# Finding least square solution for $f(t)=at+b\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)+5$

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I have three points $(t,f(t))$: $(-3,1)$, $(0,5+\sqrt{2})$ ,$(1,7)$
and want to solve for $a$ and $b$ in the following functions, such that the solution is the best approximation to the overdetermined system.

$$f(t)=at+b\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)+5$$

Now I want to set up the Matrix $A$ such that I can solve for that solution using the normal equation $A^{t}Ax=A^{t}b$.

But I'm having a little trouble setting the matrix up such that I get a system $Ax=b$. I can calculate the values $\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)$ but how do I get the $+5$ into the system:

$$A\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=y$$

It's probably a very simple fix...

Answer (score 0):

$$f(t)=at+b\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)+5$$
$$\text{With }\quad\begin{cases}y=f-5\\ x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right) \end{cases}\quad\to\quad y=at+bx$$
An usual linear regression for least squares fit will solve the problem.

Comment: This won't give the least squares fit. It will give a least square fit on the linear function but that won't be the same as the actually requested regression.

Comment: Well, for me the wording of your question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score -1):

Pick a set of $t$'s: $t_1 = -1, t_2 = 0, t_3=1$ and evaluate $\cos (\pi t_i/4) = c_i$, let $f_1 = 1, f_2 = 5\sqrt{2}, f_3=4$ and form the matrix equation
$$
\begin{pmatrix} t_1 & c_1 \\ t_2 & c_2 \\ t_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} f_1 - 5 \\ f_2 -5 \\ f_3 -5 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and solve it the way you propose...

Comment: This won't give the least squares fit.

Comment: @IanMiller funny - there are 3 answers here all saying exactly the same thing and you only downvoted mine :) why wouldn't this be least squares?

Comment: If you care to look at the time stamps yours was the only answer when I looked at this question. It will give a least square fit on the linear function but that won't be the same as the actually requested regression

Comment: As an of why its not the least square fit consider the example of fitting the data points (0,1), (1,2), (2,5) to an exponential function $A\times E^{Bx}$. An exponential fit gives $A=0.8838...$ and $B=0.8643...$ Fitting the linearized data (0,0), (1,$\ln2$), (2,$\ln5$) to the corresponding linear function $\ln A+Bx$ gives $A=0.9634...$ and $B=0.8047...$ The sum of squares of differences for these two solutions are 0.02349... and 0.05850... respectively.

Comment: @IanMiller i don't see how this is a good example -- in your problem, the coefficients appear in an inherently nonlinear form, so linearizing them makes sense. In OP's problem, they are already in the linearized form

Comment: My point was linearizing the data will not give the best fit due to the inheritance non-linearity of the transformation - each squares of differences will transform differently. The same will occur to a smaller degree with cosine which is also non-linear.

Answer (score -1):

If you are fitting $f(\mathbf{x})=a_1f_1(\mathbf{x})+\cdots+a_pf_p(\mathbf{x})+C$ where $C$ is a fixed constant such as the $5$ in your case, then the design matrix is:

$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(\mathbf{x}_1) & f_2(\mathbf{x}_1) & \cdots & f_p(\mathbf{x}_1)\\
f_1(\mathbf{x}_2) & f_2(\mathbf{x}_2) & \cdots & f_p(\mathbf{x}_2)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
f_1(\mathbf{x}_n) & f_2(\mathbf{x}_n) & \cdots & f_p(\mathbf{x}_n)\\
\end{bmatrix}$

In your problem, you have $\mathbf{x}=t$, $f_1(t)=t$, $f_2(t)=\cos\frac{\pi t}{4}$, and $n=3$. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: This won't give the least squares fit.  It will give a least square fit on the linear function but that won't be the same as the actually requested regression.